# What actually happens when we pass an array as a parameter?

Tags: c, arrays

```
void fun(int arr[8])
{
   printf("\nArray size inside fun() is %d", sizeof(arr));
}

int main()
{
   int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

   printf("Array size inside main() is %d", sizeof(arr));
   fun(arr);

   return 0;
}
```

Why the size of array `arr[8]` inside function `fun()` is 4 bytes and array `arr[8]` in function main() is 32 bytes? Although they can store 8 integers each of 4 bytes. The size of the array `arr[8]` in func() should have also been 32.

What actually happens when we pass an array as a parameter?

Comment: "What actually happens when we pass an array as a parameter?" A pointer to the first element of the array is passed. Also, although a parameter can be declared with an array type, it gets automatically adjusted to a pointer type. See C11 [6.7.6.3 paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7):

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, `sizeof` is calculating `arr` to be `8 * sizeof(int)`.  In `fun`, `sizeof` is calculating `arr` to be `sizeof(int *)`.  As you can see, an array decays to a pointer when passed to a function.

Comment: That means arr[] in fun should be treated as only a single pointer of an integer. But my question is how only a single pointer points and prints all data passing from the main function?
For example in this code: 
void fun(int arr[],int n) 
{ 
int i; 
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{ printf("%d\n",arr[i]); 
} 
}
int main()
{
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    fun(arr,5);
}

Comment: @user9817940 Look at the duplicate question. Everything is explained best there. `arr` is not a array in `fun`, it is a pointer. With this pointer you access the values of the array in the caller.

Comment: When you increment the address of an `int` pointer (e.g. `arr++`) you move to the address of the next `int`.  In this way, you can use a `int *` to access more than one element in an `int` array.